# Problema de codificación en string: Warning: (1300, "Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'F36E'")

Tags: python, pymysql

Tengo un script que se conecta a una base de datos y crea una tabla temporal con un contenido que le llega filtrado.

He probado la cláusula SQL en un cliente de base de datos (Dbeaver) y funciona correctamente; es esta:

```
create table uz_cursos2019 
(SELECT DISTINCT mdl_course.id cursoId FROM mdl_course 
join mdl_course_categories on mdl_course.category = mdl_course_categories.id  
WHERE  mdl_course_categories.path like'/2%' and mdl_course_categories.name not in ('Coordinación', 'Varios', 'Escuela de Doctorado'));
```

Pero cuando la pongo en marcha dentro del script, variando las variables que me interesan, por ejemplo así:

```
"create table "+nombre_tabla+"(SELECT DISTINCT \
            mdl_course.id cursoId \
        FROM \
            mdl_course \
            join mdl_course_categories on mdl_course.category = mdl_course_categories.id \
        WHERE \
            mdl_course_categories.path like" + camino+" \
            and mdl_course_categories.name not in ('Coordinación', 'Varios', 'Escuela de Doctorado')) "
```

me lanza el error:

> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:166: Warning: (1300, "Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'F36E'")

Me parece que el problema puede ser o bien el uso del acento que aparece por ahí o tal vez (aunque lo dudo mucho) la barra `/` que viene con la variable camino siempre.

Lo que me llama la atención es el hecho que desde el cliente funciona correctamente, pero en el script, viene el problema...

Amplío información: uso Python versión 3.5.3 y la versión de pymysql que uso es PyMySQL0.7.10

¿Se os ocurre alguna solución? (o colleja si es el caso)

Comment: El carácter `U+F36E` pertenece al [bloque privado de Unicodes](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+E000), o sea, no tiene asignado ningún carácter todavía. En principio te está dando un _"warning"_, que no un error. Supongo que mysql lo está procesando, pero es raro que estés usando un código de carácter que no tenga representación. Revisa mejor de dónde puede venir.

Comment: Warning != Error.

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestras respuesta, me han iluminado mucho. En cualquier caso, por razones ajenas a mi voluntad (mucho trabajo fundamentalmente) no puedo dedicar el tiempo que merecería la sugerencia de @ChemaCortes; y tal como ha sugerido @Alfabravo es un warning, por lo que he podido generar la información que necesitaba. De hecho, me crea correctamente las tablas temporales, y genera bien la info que buscaba. Un saludo